# Javascript function to modify the array of objects reuturns the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a data inside of my array, which looks like this.

> ```
> const arr = [
>   {
>   devSth: {
>     h1: [1],
>     h2: [1],
>   }
>  },
> ];
> ```

I have a function, which should modify this array. It looks like this:

> ```
> const modifyArr = (data) => {
>  data.forEach(el => {
>   let keys = el.devSth && Object.keys(el.devSth);
>   keys.forEach(key => {
>     el.devSth[key].map(el => {
>     return {
>     name: el,
>     val: 'lalala'
>     }
>     })
>   })
> })
> return data;
> }
> ```

Then I am using my function:

> ```
> const newArr = modifyArr(arr);
> console.log(newArr);
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> [{
>   devSth: {
>     h1: [{name: 1, val: 'lalala'}],
>     h2: [{name: 1, val: 'lalala'}]
>   }
> }]
> ```

Actual output:

> ```
> [{
>   devSth: {
>     h1: [1],
>     h2: [1]
>   }
> }]
> ```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're not assigning the `.map` results to anything. `.map` doesn't modify in place, it instead returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

you are mapping the values, but not setting them (line 5) :

```
const modifyArr = (data) => {
 data.forEach(el => {
  let keys = el.devSth && Object.keys(el.devSth);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    el.devSth[key] = el.devSth[key].map(el => {
    return {
    name: el,
    val: 'lalala'
    }
    })
  })
})
return data;
}
```

this is untested.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I missed that

Answer (score 1):

You dont assign the result of the `.map` operation back to the original keys `h1` and `h2`. So it doesn't modify those.

Just change

```
            el.devSth[key].map(el => {
                return {
                    name: el,
                    val: 'lalala'
                }
            })
```

to

```
            el.devSth[key] = el.devSth[key].map(el => {
                return {
                    name: el,
                    val: 'lalala'
                }
```

```js
const arr = [{
  devSth: {
    h1: [1],
    h2: [1],
  }
}, ];

const modifyArr = (data) => {
  data.forEach(el => {
    let keys = el.devSth && Object.keys(el.devSth);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      el.devSth[key] = el.devSth[key].map(el => {
        return {
          name: el,
          val: 'lalala'
        }
      })
    })
  })
  return data;
}

const newArr = modifyArr(arr);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, just missed it)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing it:

```js
const arr = [{
  devSth: {h1: [1], h2: [1]}
}];

let obj = arr[0].devSth, number;

for (const prop in obj){
  number = obj[prop][0];
  obj[prop] = [{name: number, val: 'lalala'}];
}

console.log([{devSth: obj}])
```